# Test Google Chrome on Android using WebDriver

Tags: java, android, selenium, webdriver

We have a requirement to test Google Chrome on Android Emulator using WebDriver. I am using WebDriver and I am able to test on default browser by installing Selenium Server on Android Emulator. But when I set desired capabilities as chrome and platform Android using RemoteWebDriver, I am able to start tests but it opens default browser and not chrome. Any ideas!?

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet possible with Android.

Currently you can only run webdriver tests against the apk built by Selenium, which is not the Google Chrome browser.

Comment: This isn't true anymore it seems, see other answers

Answer (score 1):

At GTAC 2013 Ken Kania (a Google Engineer) announced the alpha of the Chrome Driver for Android during his presentation. https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/14xU207jL1aepO_8-WrkEcSIPUscUjak5jtxMaUoMegg/pub?start=false&loop=false#slide=id.gbe6ac7bc_0129

The documentation was recently moved to the following site, it's still spartan
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run test on Chrome on android device using Chrome driver. I am using [QAF (formerly ISFW) - Selenium Framework](http://qmetry.github.io/qaf) and i provided following configuration:

selenium.defaultBrowser=chromeDriver

chrome.aditional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"androidPackage":"com.android.chrome"}}

For non ISFW user detailed information is available on [Chrome driver wiki page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android).